# How to create merge requests for different targets from the same origin branch?

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, git-push

Let's say there are 3 branches: test, test2 and test3.

The goal is to create 2 merge requests:

- From test to test2.
- From test to test3.

The following command correctly creates the merge request in GitLab for test2 (branch test is active):

```
git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=test2
```

I believed that running the same for target=test3 would create another.
But instead it changes the target for the previously created merge request from test2 to test3.

Passing along a title also doesn't change the behaviour.

I looked into all the available options (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-merge-requests) but I couldn't find a solution.

Is this possible? The only alternative I can think of is the use the GitLab API.

Comment: I would _assume_ that if you push the branch with a different name, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I considered this also. But I really would like to keep the same branch to avoid other issues. In the GitLab frontend it's possible to create the above constellation.